# how to sent message in handler to specific handler only

Tags: android

how to sent message inside handler??? in my app so many handler im using number suppose if i want to sent mesage to handler number 11 what i wil do?? suppose if i want to sent string"hello world" also with handler what will i do????

```
                      try{
                               }



                     catch (Exception e) {

        android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
        alertMessage.what = 11;
        //i want to sent message"hello wrold" also what i do                                            
               handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
                               }




                              Handler handle = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
                       if (msg.what == 11) {
            try {

               //show messgae"helloworld" here
                                     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
alertMessage.what = 11;
alertMessage.obj = "test message"; //this is how you send an object (in this case a string)
handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);


//then in your handler
Handler handle = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
         if (msg.what == 11) {
             String text = (String)msg.obj; //here is your text message
         }

    }
}
```